# How to prove or disprove the matrices formula

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Could some one give me some hints about the following prove of disprove:

(a) If $PXX^TP^T=QXX^TQ^T$, then $PX=QX$;

(b) If $PXX^T=QXX^T$, then $PX=QX$.

In the above formulas, $P$, $Q$ and $X$ are appropriate dimension matrices.

I have no ideas about the above deduction. Could some one help me？ Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Say $X$ is the identity, then the formula in (a) says that if $PP^T=QQ^T$, then $P=Q$. This is obviously wrong in general (think of the orthogonal group that does not consist of only one element).

Comment: @frog,  why does $PP^T = QQ^T$ imply $P = Q?$

Comment: @abel: What I meant is that the implication is wrong since for all elements $A,B$ (particularly distinct elements) in $\mathrm O(n)$, you will have $AA^T=BB^T=\mathrm{id}_n$. So the implication is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (b), "$PXX^T=QXX^T$ implies $PX=QX$" is equivalent (with $R:=P-Q$) to "$RXX^T=0$ implies $RX=0$". This is true since if $RXX^T=0$, $$\|RX\|_F^2=\mathrm{trace}(\underbrace{RXX^T}_{=0}R^T)=0$$ and hence $RX=0$. It can also be seen from the fact that $RX=0$ if and only if $Rx=0$ for all $x$ in the range of $X$ and by noticing that $X$ and $XX^T$ have the same range.

On the other hand, (a) is not true in general. Setting $A:=PX$ and $B:=QX$, it is equivalent (as already pointed out in the comment) to "$AA^T=BB^T$ implies $A=B$". But take, e.g., $A\neq B$ with
$$
A=[1,0], \quad B=[0,1].
$$
We have $AA^T=BB^T=1$ though.